# If $f'$ is Lipschitz continuous with constant $c$, then $f(y)-f(x)-f'(x)(y-x)\ge-\frac c2(y-x)^2$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, taylor-expansion, lipschitz-functions

> Let $f\in C^1(\mathbb R)$ and assume $f'$ is Lipschitz continuous with Lipschitz constant $c\ge 0$. How can we show that $$f(y)-f(x)-f'(x)(y-x)\ge-\frac c2(y-x)^2\tag1$$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb R$?

I don't understand where the factor $\frac12$ on the right-hand side comes from. And I think we need to assume $x\le y$, don't we?

If $x\le y$, then (by the mean value theorem) there is a $z\in[x,y]$ with $$f(y)-f(x)=f'(z)(y-x)=\left(f'(z)-f'(z)+f'(x)\right)(y-x)\tag2.$$ By Lipschitz continuity, $$\left|f'(z)-f'(x)\right|\le c(z-x)\le c(y-x)\tag3$$ and hence $$f'(z)-f'(x)\ge-c(y-x).\tag4$$ Thus, $$f(y)-f(x)-f'(x)(y-x)=\left(f'(z)-f'(x)\right)(y-x)\ge-c(y-x)^2.\tag5$$

> How can we obtain the stronger conclusion $(1)$?

Comment: I mean the factor of $\frac{1}{2}$ makes it a stronger statement. You proved a weaker statement. What's the issue?

Comment: @mathworker21 The issue is that I want to obtain the stronger statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that
$$f(y)=f(x)+\int_x^y f'(t)dt=f(x)+f'(x)(y-x)+\int_x^y (f'(t)-f'(x))dt.$$
Therefore 
$$\begin{align}
f(y)-f(x)-f'(x)(y-x)&=\int_x^y (f'(t)-f'(x))dt \\
&\geq -\int_{\min(x,y)}^{\max(x,y)} |f'(t)-f'(x)|dt\\
&\geq -c\int_{\min(x,y)}^{\max(x,y)}  |t-x|dt=-\frac{c}{2}(y-x)^2.
\end{align}$$

Comment: Hello! May I ask about your last equality? Suppose $x < y$. Then we have $$-c \int_x^y|t-x|dt = -c \int_x^y( t-x) dt  = (\frac{t^2}{2} - tx|_x^y = -c[(\frac{y^2}{2} - xy) - (\frac {x^2}{2} - x^2) ]=-c[ \dfrac {1}{2} (x-y)^2 + x^2]$$. Did I miss something here?

Comment: Check the last step... $(\frac{y^2}{2} - xy) - (\frac {x^2}{2} - x^2)=\frac{y^2}{2} - xy+\frac {x^2}{2}=\frac{(y-x)^2}{2}$.

Comment: Oh of course, thanks a lot